# Average rating query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like so

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| restaurantid | rating | customerid |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

I would like to find the worldwide average rating of only the restaurants that a particular customerid has reviewed by using avg(rating) in sql query.

E.g:

```
SELECT avg(rating) FROM ratings WHERE customerid=17.
```

But, that same restaurant will have been reviewed by others as well. So the above query only calculates avg over only the rows for customerid=17 instead of taking into account other people who might have rated the restaurant.

I would like the avg value to be average of all customers and not just customerid #17. But I would like to show only the rows for customerid #17. One restaurant can be reviewed multiple times by the same customer.

E.g:

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| restaurantid | rating | customerid |
+--------------+--------+------------+
|            1 |      2 |         34 |
|            2 |      3 |         35 |
|            3 |      1 |         17 |
|            4 |      2 |          5 |
|            5 |      2 |         17 |
|            3 |      4 |         17 |
|            8 |      3 |          4 |
|            3 |      5 |         88 |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

Now I am looking to get (average rating across everyone who has rated the particular restaurant)

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| restaurantid | rating | customerid |
+--------------+--------+------------+
|            3 |    3.4 |         17 |
|            5 |      2 |         17 |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

But what I am getting is (average rating over 2 rows for the 2 ratings for restaurant #3 given by customerid #17)

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| restaurantid | rating | customerid |
+--------------+--------+------------+
|            3 |    2.5 |         17 |
|            5 |      2 |         17 |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Edited the schema. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple aggregation after you filter the `restaurantid`s:

```
select restaurantid, 
       avg(rating) rating, 
       17 customerid 
from ratings
where restaurantid in (select restaurantid from ratings where customerid = 17)
group by restaurantid;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ej7sq1qY77zXFvivJcSw1J/1).
Results:

```
| restaurantid | rating | customerid |
| ------------ | ------ | ---------- |
| 3            | 3.3333 | 17         |
| 5            | 2      | 17         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a customer does not review the same restaurant multiple times, then you can `join` and aggregate:

```
select rc.restaurantid, rc.customerid, avg(r.rating) as other_rating,
       rc.rating as my_rating
from rating r join
     rating rc
     on r.restaurantid = rc.restaurantid
where rc.customerid = 17
group by rc.restaurantid, rc.customerid, rc.rating;
```

EDIT:

You can handle multiple reviews of a single restaurant by pre-aggregating:

```
select rc.restaurantid, rc.customerid, avg(r.rating) as other_rating,
       rc.rating as my_rating
from rating r join
     (select restaurantid, avg(rating) as rating
      from rating rc
      group by restuarantid
     ) rc
     on r.restaurantid = rc.restaurantid
where rc.customerid = 17
group by rc.restaurantid, rc.customerid, rc.rating;
```

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, one restaurant can be reviewed multiple times by the same customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select restaurantid, avg_rating, 17 as customerid
    from (
             select restaurantid, avg(rating) as avg_rating
             from ratings
             group by restaurantid)
    where restaurantid in (select restaurantid from ratings where customerid = 17);
```

produces the following output:

```
    3,3.3333333333333335,17
    5,2,17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT avg(rating) FROM ratings WHERE customerid=17.
```

Or this

```
SELECT avg(sum(rating)) FROM ratings WHERE customerid=17.
```